# htaccess rewrite rule to ignore end portion of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am moving a site from IIS to Apache and part of the transition requires a change in URL handling.

The current URL pattern is:

```
http://example.com/articles/tabid/110/ID/1691/simple_friendly_name_of_page.aspx
```

1691 is the unique id of the post. It consists of two or more digits.

I would like to use .htaccess so as to ignore the "simple_friendly_name_of_page.aspx". Please bear in mind that the aforementioned aspx page can contain UTF-8 characters above the ASCII range (Hebrew, Greek etc)
In essence, I would like to permanently (301) redirect requests for

```
http://example.com/articles/tabid/110/ID/1691/simple_friendly_name_of_page.aspx
```

to

```
http://example.com/articles/tabid/110/ID/1691
```

I imagine that this has to do with

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://example.com/articles/tabid/110/ID/(.*)/(.*)
```

but I cannot grasp the regex needed for the other part of redirect / mod-rewrite. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^articles/tabid/([0-9]+)/ID/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ articles/tabid/$1/ID/$2 [R=301]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/articles/tabid/([0-9]+)/ID/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://example.com/articles/tabid/$1/ID/$2
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it this afternoon and get back with the results. From what I understand "$2" will always equal the value in "/ID/([0-9]+)/(.*)$" ?

Comment: @PeterTheraux: $1 = result from 1st regexp expression, $2 = result from 2nd regexp, $3 = results from 3rd regexp etc.